# Black stains and discoloration on outer foundation wall of a house - water damage?

Tags: foundation, water-damage, old-house

The outside foundation wall of this house has visible black stains and discoloration.  The house is a bungalow built around 1970.  No way to tell what the inside of the foundation looks like (covered with drywall/paneling).

The house is located within 1000 feet of water, but it's on relatively flat ground.

Is this a sign of water damage to the foundation, or is it just dirt?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I do not think the mold is from high water.
I would say it is more likely on a shaded portion of the home on next to an area with a lawn. notice the path in the snow a walkway on the front section? The damage to the bottom of the window  possibly from shade or lawn being watered but doubtful that it is caused from flooding, notice how it ends and the “rust” stains on the wall above the mold and to the left.
With the info in the photo I would say it’s not a high water issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just dirt, splash back from rain/etc falling off your roof.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same on my foundation and, after quite a bit of research, I found it to simply be dirt that had hit the foundation after hard rain storms. I was able to remove my with a combination of scrubbing with soapy water and a bristle brush as well as periodic power washing.

This black staining was worse on my home in the areas where there are no gutters and where driving rain storms could hit bare dirt near the fountain.

Clean it up, put some gravel down, and it won't come back.